# Isobaric process: is there some missing parameter?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, gas

I'm working on a supposedly rather easy problem in thermodynamics, and yet I cannot solve it. The problem states:

"A certain quantity of Freon gas is contained in a cylinder with mobile walls. It undergoes to an isochoric expansion, with $P = 2.5\cdot 10^5$ Pa. The work done by the gas is $4500$ Joules. Calculate the initial volume of the gas."

Isn't there some missing parameter? I know that in this case we have $P_A = P_B$, and $W = P \Delta V$. Yet I can only find $\Delta V$, not $V_A$ as requested.

I have no other information.

Thank you!

Comment: Isochoric means "constant volume" but then the work is zero. Do you mean isobaric, as in "constant pressure"?

Comment: @Themis Uh, sorry! My big bad, going to edit! Yes I meant isobaric!

Comment: In this case you’re right, you can only calculate $\Delta V$ if all you know is pressure and work.